# How i create duplicate format block with opentbs plugins

Tags: php, opentbs, tinybutstrong

I am trying to make duplicate format row with TinyButStrong word document. The data have grouping each title of activity but i cannot make spesific format templete document in .docx
[data sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzAFl.png)
the format i have to create is like this
[format export](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFpYy.png)

Answer (score 0):

TinyButStrong, has a grouping feature, for this kind of purpose.
Of course it works with OpenTBS + DOCX.

That is parameter `headergrp`.

See the [manual](https://www.tinybutstrong.com/manual.php#html_block_section) and [examples](https://www.tinybutstrong.com/examples.php?e=grouping&m=result).